# I'm getting question marks instead of letters in textView android

Tags: android, json

I'm experiencing some problems with characters and didn't have that problem till now. First i would like to say that i'm parsing Json here. This activity is receiving data from Json in listView from previous activity. If you can see in First picture i'm getting in textView question marks instead of letters and in the second picture i'm getting fine letters. I don't know what is the problem because the whole code for the first and for the second activity is almost the same. Does anyone have any suggestion or know why is this happening?

Thank you.

[image: First Layout]
[image: Second Layout]

Comment: For what letters are you getting question marks, can you name a few?

Comment: š, ć, č, ž, đ These letters

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 String data="yout datacontent";
 yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(data);
```

In  JSON parsing

**UTF-8 charset.**

```
  String name = "";
   try {
   name = new String(c.getString("NAME").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
   } 
  catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

   e.printStackTrace();
  }
        String decodedName = Html.fromHtml(name).toString();
         yourTextView.setText(decodedName )
```

Comment: I have not used that code in my second activity and everything was working fine. Is this could be something in Json file?

Comment: Html.fromHtml() is using TagSoup for parsing HTML and not JSON, how does that help in this case?

Comment: http://nadji-ekipu.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/bioskop.txt This is json for activity where i'm getting question marks and i find out that letters are not the same i have written and http://nadji-ekipu.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/movies.txt this is json when i'm getting fine letters in activity. I have used the same letters for both json. Why i'm getting in one chyrilic characters?

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic I have tested both Json, and they are syntatically correct. In what program have you written the Jsons? was it the same, using the same encode? If so, check [here](http://www.json.org/) for the encode detail on Strings.

Comment: I have solved this. In first file i was using for encoding UTF 8 with BOM and in second without, so i change encoding to UTF 8 with BOM and letters are showing excellent.